# ember-rails & handlebars: specified templateName does not exist for one view, but does for all others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-rails

I'm working up an ember-rails app that precompiles Handlebars assets through the rails pipeline. Everything is updated to the latest versions via `bundle update`.

When we load the index, the ember data is not rendered to the list, despite (app/views/gigs/index.html.erb):

```
<h1>Gigs</h1>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{ view App.ListGigsView }}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    App.gigsController.loadAll(<%= @gigs.to_json.html_safe %>);
  });
</script>
```

So, I checked the ListGigsView, which contains the following (app/assets/javascripts/app/views/gigs/list.js):

```
App.ListGigsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:    'app/templates/gigs/list',
  gigsBinding: 'App.gigsController',

  showNew: function() {
    this.set('isNewVisible', true);
  },

  hideNew: function() {
this.set('isNewVisible', false);
  },

 refreshListing: function() {
    App.gigsController.findAll()
  }

 });
```

Seems like the templateName is pointing fine (this is similar in, say, new.js). Nonetheless, the browser console (Google Chrome Version 25.0.1364.172) keeps returning the following:

`Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You specified the templateName app/templates/gigs/list for <App.ListGigsView:ember194>, but it did not exist.`

Here is the file at app/assets/javascripts/app/templates/gigs/list.handlebars:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{#each gigs}}
    {{view App.ShowGigView gigBinding="this"}}
  {{/each}}
 {{#if isNewVisible}}
    <tr>
      <td>*</td>
      <td>
        {{view App.NewGigView}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/if}}
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <div class="commands">
  <a href="#" {{action "showNew"}}>New Gig</a>
  <a href="#" {{action "refreshListing"}}>Refresh Listing</a>
</div>
```

Why is the template not rendering? Running `Ember.TEMPLATES` in the console returns all the other view template links intact:

```
> Ember.TEMPLATES
=> Object {app/templates/gigs/edit: function, app/templates/gigs/event: function, app/templates/gigs/show: function, application: function}
```

But not the one for `list`. Why is that template AWOL?

- For reference, I am running the following according to the browser console:

  Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1 ember.js:339
  Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3 ember.js:339
  jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1

-Edit: I have just discovered that including the Handlebars reference to the Event view in index.html.erb causes that template to disappear,too:

```
<h1>Gigs</h1>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{ view App.ListGigsView }}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{ view App.EventView }}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    App.gigsController.loadAll(<%= @gigs.to_json.html_safe %>);
  });
</script>
```

Why does this happen? And how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

`app/templates/` gets stripped from the template name by default. Try `gigs/list`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when stripping out `templates`, e.g. `app/gigs/list`.